# Mongoose query wont work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am doing this query to find the book with id "345" and which has a string "jack" in its owner array.

But it only lookes for the owner part and doesnt query id. Am i doing a syntax mistake?

```
Book.findOne({owner:{$in:["jack"]} },{_id:"345"},function(err,data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the `owner` and `_id` properties of the find selector need to be in the same object:

```js
Book.findOne({owner:{$in:["jack"]}, _id:"345"}, function(err,data) {...});
```